# How to default to another property when the first is null or undefined using ES6 Object destructuring

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, object-destructuring

Looking for a neat way to access a second non-null property from an object when then first property is null or undefined using ES6 object destructuring.

ES5 equivalent:

```
var obj = { a: null, b: 2 };
var num = obj.a || obj.b; // num = 2
```

Using ES6 (something like):

```
const { num: a || b } = obj; // <- how to achieve the above effect here?
```

Comment: There's no such syntax (yet). You can only ```const { a, b } = obj, num = a || b;```

Comment: Default syntax in function args and destructuring only applies for `undefined` so if you want default logic for both null and undefined, you need to do it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

```
 const { a: num = obj.b } = obj;
```

(That only works with `undefined`, not with `null`)

or

```
const num = (({a, b}) => a || b)(obj)
```

Comment: I tried the first, and when I try to access `num` I get a reference error.

Comment: @barmar, yup, edited, took it over from OP without thinking about it ...

Comment: Use [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to put the test cases here instead of an external site.

Answer (score 0):

Default values in destructuring work only with `undefined`, not `null`. With

```
var obj = { a: undefined, b: 2}
```

you could use the horrible hack

```
var { b: num, a: num = num } = obj;
```

or its more readable variant

```
const { b, a: num = b } = obj;
```

which however introduces an additional identifier `b` in the scope.